# Finding An Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have came the the following matrix

$$(u^2+1)^2 \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&u^2 \end{pmatrix} $$

To calculate the inverse should I return to

$$ \begin{pmatrix} (u^2+1)^2&0\\ 0&u^2(u^2+1)^2 \end{pmatrix} $$

using $$\frac{1}{(ad-bc)}\begin{pmatrix} d&-b\\ -c&a \end{pmatrix}$$

Or can I calualate it immediatly

Comment: no need to multiply through. Compute first the inverse of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 &0\\ 0 & u^2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ using the formula you listed, and then divide by $(u^2+1)^2$

Comment: Also, it's a diagonal matrix, so there isn't much to think about when it comes to computing the inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(cA^{-1})=c^{-1}A^{-1}$, for a non-zero constant $c$ and an invertible matrix $A$. Any diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries is invertible such that $\left[\begin{array}{cc}d_1&0\\ 0&d_2\end{array}\right]^{-1}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}d_1^{-1}&0\\ 0&d_2^{-1}\end{array}\right]$

Answer (score 1):

Either way you suggest will work.  If you didn't want to distribute $(u^2+1)^2$ into the matrix then you could use the fact that $$(cA)^{-1} = \frac{1}{c}A^{-1}$$ provided $A$ is invertible and $c\neq0$.